# Does IPP thread safe when it linked to the non-threaded static library?

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, intel-ipp

Does IPP thread safe when it linked to the non-threaded static library ?

Answer (score -1):

IPP does not care about threads, because it has little to no state information that would need to be protected.

Comment: Not all IPP functions are threadsafe. 
https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-integrated-performance-primitives-intel-ipp-threading-openmp-faq#2

Comment: The multithreaded functions are newer than my answer. Using the regular IPP functions requires you to do your own synchronisation if there is ever any shared data (which there normally isn't).